# Save data to a datatable created in another class?

Tags: c#, wpf, class

I'm rather new to c# and very new to wpf so please forgive me if this is a really stupid question....

I have three classes. Here is the structure of my program.

In the MainWindow class a few initialization steps should be done, one of them is that a datatable is created by using a method in another class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            savelabels table = new savelabels();
            table.createlabeltable();
            //...some other stuff that works
          }
}
```

Here the class in which the datatable should be created, filled and on demand returned:

```
    public class savelabels
        {
            DataTable labelcoords = new DataTable();

            public void createlabeltable()
            {
                DataColumn column;              

                column = new DataColumn();
                column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double");
                column.ColumnName = "id";
                labelcoords.Columns.Add(column);

            }

            public void saveposition(double x)
            {
                DataRow row = labelcoords.NewRow();
                row["id"] = x;

                labelcoords.Rows.Add(row);

            }

        public DataTable GetDataTable()  
        {
            return labelcoords;
        }
}
```

Then I have this third class in which there is a method which should fill the datatable:

```
    public class getdata
    {

        public void filltable()
        {
            double x = 123;
            savelabels ctable = new savelabels();
            ctable.saveposition(x);  
        }

}
```

I want to use the values that are written into the table by the saveposition method by other methods also in the getdata class. The Problem is that not even the saveposition(x) method is working as there is no "id" column in the labelcoords table, so I guess the table that is created in the MainWindow class cannot be accessed by the saveposition method.

Comment: Why don't you just move the filltable method into the savelabels class? Your get data class has no reference to the savelabels class so they don't share the same DataTable instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to access a class instance from another class instance, you'll need to pass the instance into it. I don't see you creating an instance of `getdata`, so I can't refactor any. But, it would be something like `YourgetdataInstance.filltable(savelabels mytable)` and in it, you'd drop the instantiating of a new instance and just use `mytable.saveposition(x)`. Since the method explicity expects a certain structure, I'd be inclined to go with what simon suggested in the comment.

However, if you want to keep the `filltable` in a separate class, you can provide a parameter like I showed. If you aren't needing an actual instance of `getdata`, you can change it to a `static` class so you can call it directly.

Comment: Thx, in the end I fixed it by simply moving everthing to the getdata class....seems to be the easiest and maybe even most efficient way in this case.